# Query execution is slow in Teradata FastExport compared to Default Connection

Tags: teradata, fastexport

I have a small doubt on how to use fastexport in production environment.

I have a million rows file and am using fastload to upload it to TD which is taking almost a minute and doing some business logic and when i use fastexport for downloading the table to my local machine/node, it is taking very long time compared to the default version.

Connection Uri i am using is :

jdbc:teradata://server/TMODE=ANSI,CHARSET=UTF8,TYPE=FASTEXPORT

Am i missing anything here. Please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: Workload management rules including concurrent utilities, sessions allocated to JDBC FastExport vs. TPT FastExport vs. Legacy FastExport. The complexity of the SQL statement used to extract the data and workload management rules applied to it. Are you pulling from a view or a table? Have you spoken to the DBA team?

Comment: Hi @RobPaller, Thanks for the answer. I spoke to the DBA team and they said the number looks good but i am not satisfied as it is much higher than the download using DEFAULT options. I am downloading data from a table and not from view.